# Нужна помошь с MySQL запросом для реализации фильтров

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Делаю фильтр для фильтрации товаров.
Допустим, у меня есть следующая структура:
**products** (Таблица товаров)

- id
- category_id

**filters_values** (Значения фильтров)
 - id
 - filter_id
 - value

**products_values** (Таблица для связки товара со значением фильтра)
 - prod_id
 - val_id

Есть n-ое кол-во фильтров:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К примеру, я выбираю в фильтре Gray и рост 128. Т.е., должны показаться все товары серого цвета, у которых рос 128, но у меня показываются все товары серого цвета (у которых рост не обязательно 128) и все товары с ростом 128 (которые не обязательно серого цвета).

Использую следующий запрос:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `p`.*
FROM (`products` p, `products_values` pv)
WHERE `p`.`category_id` = '223' AND `p`.`id` = pv.prod_id AND `p`.`active` = 1 AND
      (pv.val_id = '200' OR `pv`.`val_id` = '223')
ORDER BY `price` ASC
LIMIT 12
```

`val_id = 200` - это цвет gray, `val_id = 223` - это размер 128.

Как правильно связать таблицы?

Comment: `pv.val_id = '200' OR pv.val_id = '223'` как раз и говорит: выбрать если один из параметров соответствует заданному. Если надо чтобы применялись все фильтры одновременно, то только джойнить таблицу фильтров по разу на каждый фильтр и объединять разные фильтры по AND, либо переделывать структуру БД

Answer (score 3):

надо объединить таблицу товаров с **двумя** экземплярами таблицы значений.

примерно так:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc1cb/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table p (id int, n text);
insert into p values
   (1, "трусики")
  ,(2, "лифчики")
  ,(3, "маечки")
;

create table v (p int, z int);
insert into v values
   (1, 200)
  ,(1, 223)
  ,(2, 200)
  ,(3, 223)  
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from p
join v as v1 on p.id = v1.p and v1.z = 200
join v as v2 on p.id = v2.p and v2.z = 223
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc1cb/2/0)**:

```
| id |       n | p |   z | p |   z |
|----|---------|---|-----|---|-----|
|  1 | трусики | 1 | 200 | 1 | 223 |
```